# Implementing the functionality fo transaction annotations using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, transactions, ejb-3.0

I'm using Hibernate in a non-EJB environment. I know that there are several [Transation Annotations](http://tomee.apache.org/transaction-annotations.html) when using EJBs. But the [Hibernate Documentation](https://community.jboss.org/wiki/SessionsAndTransactions#Transaction_demarcation_with_plain_JDBC) does not seem to discuss all these scenarios. What I want to know is when running the code

```
try {
    factory.getCurrentSession().beginTransaction();

    // Do some work
    factory.getCurrentSession().load(...);
    factory.getCurrentSession().persist(...);

    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().commit();
}
catch (RuntimeException e) {
    factory.getCurrentSession().getTransaction().rollback();
    throw e; // or display error message
}
```

what will happen there is already a transaction running?(Will a new transaction be created or will the existing transaction be used. If it is the latter how do I achieve the former and vise versa?)
How can I achieve the same functionality as the different EJB annotations using Hibernate?

Answer (score 2):

[The javadoc of `beginTransaction()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Session.html#beginTransaction%28%29) says:

> Begin a unit of work and return the associated Transaction object. If a new underlying transaction is required, begin the transaction. Otherwise continue the new work in the context of the existing underlying transaction.

And [the javadoc of `commit()`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Transaction.html#commit%28%29) says:

> This method will commit the underlying transaction if and only if the underlying transaction was initiated by this object.

That said, managing transactions and exceptions explicitely in code is a pain, and reduces the readability of the code. I would use Spring to solve this in a non-EJB environment.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But as you have said `continue the new work in the context of the existing underlying transaction.`, is it not possible with Hibernate to achieve the same functionality as the annotation REQUIRES_NEW?

Comment: It is: by opening a new session.